# Sybase Table Update Disable

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I just want to do inserts/deletes and don't allow any update.

Is it possible to disable updates on a table?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- Because it's friday ...
REVOKE UPDATE ON hair TO pubic;
```

Comment: NOTE to the humorless RWA moderator: pun intended. Thank you.